# How to convert HEX to NSString in Objective-C j?

Tags: ios, objective-c, decode

I have a NSString with hex string like "&# x62a;&# x631;&# x642;&# x628;" which means "ترقب".

Now I want to convert the hex string into another NSString object which shows "ترقب". How to do that ?

Comment: That appears to be an "escaped" string, but I don't know what escape scheme it is.  It's not "URL encoding", from what I can tell.  (On the other hand, it may simply be what NSLog prints when handed the UTF string for your Arabic(?) characters.  You need to see what it looks like when displayed in a label.)

Comment: @HotLicks - Take the spaces out after the #'s and its just HTML escapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSMutableString *) hextostring:(NSString *) str{
    //&#x62a;
    NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#" withString:@"0"];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"z;"];
    NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

    for (int i =0; i<[arr count]; i++) {
        if ([[arr objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"z"]) {
            [string appendString:@" "];
        } else {
            unsigned x;

            [[NSScanner scannerWithString: [arr objectAtIndex:i]] scanHexInt: &x];
            [string appendFormat:@"%C",(unichar)x];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",string);
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string looks like HTML escape sequences, except for the spaces after the #'s. If this is really what you have (check something isn't just displaying Unicode as escapes) then there is a myriad of ways to convert it. You can just process the string picking out the hex chars and producing `UniChar` values from them, etc.

If you want a high-level, maybe somewhat long-winded approach, you and try:

```
- (NSString *)decodeHTMLescapes:(NSString *)raw
{
   NSString *nospaces = [raw stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]; // one way to remove the spaces
   const char *cString = [nospaces UTF8String]; // C string
   NSData *bytes = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)cString length:strlen(cString) freeWhenDone:NO]; // as bytes
   NSAttributedString *attributed = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:bytes documentAttributes:nil]; // interpret as HTML
   NSString *decoded = attributed.string; // and finally as plain text
   return decoded;
}
```

That (a) strips the spaces, (b) creates a C string and (c) creates a byte buffer, all that so we can (d) interpret that byte buffer as HTML, and (e) finally gets the string back. The use of `initWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:` is to reduce the copying all this does.

Use it like:

```
NSString *raw = @"&# x62a;&# x631;&# x642;&# x628;";
NSString *decoded = [self decodeHTMLescapes:raw];
NSLog(@"%@ -> %@", raw, decoded);
```

HTH